# Apply regmatches function to a list of chr in R

Tags: r, regex, string, function, apply

I have this list of character stored in a variable called `x`:

```r
x <- 
  c(
    "images/logos/france2.png", 
    "images/logos/cnews.png",
    "images/logos/lcp.png", 
    "images/logos/europe1.png",
    "images/logos/rmc-bfmtv.png",
    "images/logos/sudradio.png",
    "images/logos/franceinfo.png"
  )
  
pattern <- "images/logos/\\s*(.*?)\\s*.png"

regmatches(x, regexec(pattern, x))[[1]][2]
```

I wish to extract a portion of each `chr` string according to a pattern, like this function does, which works fine but only for the first item in the list.

```
pattern <- "images/logos/\\s*(.*?)\\s*.png"

y <- regmatches(x, regexec(pattern, x))[[1]][2]
```

Only returns:

```
"france2"
```

How can I apply the `regmatches` function to all items in the list in order to get a result like this?

```
[1] "france2"    "europe1"    "sudradio"  
[4] "cnews"      "rmc-bfmtv"  "franceinfo"
[7] "lcp"        "rmc"        "lcp"
```

*FYI this is a list of `src` tags that comes from a scraper*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output of `regmatches(..., regexec(...))` is a list. You may use `sapply` to extract the 2nd element from each element of the list.

```
sapply(regmatches(x, regexec(pattern, x)), `[[`, 2)

#[1] "france2"    "europe1"    "sudradio"   "cnews"   "rmc-bfmtv"  "franceinfo"
#[7] "lcp"        "rmc"        "lcp"
```

---

You may also use the function `basename` + `file_path_sans_ext` from `tools` package which would give the required output directly.

```
tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(x))
#[1] "france2"    "europe1"    "sudradio"   "cnews"   "rmc-bfmtv"  "franceinfo"
#[7] "lcp"        "rmc"        "lcp"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `gsub`

```
gsub(
  ".*/(.*)\\.png", "\\1",
  c(
    "images/logos/france2.png", "images/logos/cnews.png",
    "images/logos/lcp.png", "images/logos/europe1.png",
    "images/logos/rmc-bfmtv.png", "images/logos/sudradio.png",
    "images/logos/franceinfo.png"
  )
)
```

which gives

```
[1] "france2"    "cnews"      "lcp"        "europe1"    "rmc-bfmtv"
[6] "sudradio"   "franceinfo"
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  strings = c("images/logos/france2.png","images/logos/cnews.png",
              "images/logos/lcp.png","images/logos/europe1.png",
              "images/logos/rmc-bfmtv.png","images/logos/sudradio.png",
              "images/logos/franceinfo.png")
)

df %>% 
  mutate(strings = str_remove(strings, "images/logos/") %>% 
           str_remove("\\.png"))

#>      strings
#> 1    france2
#> 2      cnews
#> 3        lcp
#> 4    europe1
#> 5  rmc-bfmtv
#> 6   sudradio
#> 7 franceinfo
```

---

Or even simpler:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(strings = str_extract(strings, "(?<=images/logos/)(.*)(?=\\.png)"))

#>      strings
#> 1    france2
#> 2      cnews
#> 3        lcp
#> 4    europe1
#> 5  rmc-bfmtv
#> 6   sudradio
#> 7 franceinfo
```